# Nested collection using Criteria: How to retrieve table1.getTable2().get(0) using criteria

Tags: hibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-mapping, nhibernate-projections

I have 2 tables TABLE1 and TABLE2.
hibernate class of TABLE1

class Table1
{

private Collection< table2s> table2s= new ArrayList< table2s>();

}

Now using criteria I need to fetch  Table1 records and the results should have Table2s one records among list which is linked to Table1.

eg: TABLE 1 
TABLE1ID  NAME
1         A
2         B
TABLE 2 
TABLE2ID TABLE1ID TABLE2NAME
1           1       XXXXX
2           1       XXXXXX
3           1       XXX
4           2       YYYY
5           2       YYYYYY

Expected Output:
TABLE1ID  NAME TABLE2ID  TABLE2NAME
1         A     1          XXXXX
2         B     4          YYYY

something like table1.gettable2s().get(0)

Answer (score 0):

use join() method

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Table1> q = cb.createQuery(Table1.class);
    Root<Table1> r = q.from(Table2.class);

    Join<Table2, Table1> usersJoin = r.join("field", JoinType.LEFT);
```